# iOS Delegate Not Working with UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, delegates

I have 2 UIViewControllers, GameController and RhythmController. 
I defined RhythmDelegate in **RhythmController.h** like this. 
doEndGame method in RhythmController is supposed to call the delegate method in GameController gameOver, which implements the delegate protocol.

I can't understand why this is not working... is my code in error? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
@class RhythmView,RhythmDelegate, RhythmController;

@protocol RhythmDelegate
@required
-(void)gameOver:(RhythmController*)aRhythmController;
@end

@interface RhythmController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
.....

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSObject<RhythmDelegate>* delegate;
```

Within RhythmController.m I have the delegate call going like this :

```
@implementation RhythmController
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)doEndGame{

isPaused = true;
[delegate gameOver:self];
}
```

I confirm that the doEndGame is called with a breakpoint inside. However, it doesn't go to the method I want in GameController, which implements the delegate.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CoinsController.h"
#import "CoinsGame.h"
#import "HighscoreController.h"
#import "RhythmController.h"
#import "RhythmView.h"

@interface GameController : UIViewController <RhythmDelegate> {

IBOutlet UIView *landscapePlayView;
IBOutlet UIView *landscapeGameHolderView;
IBOutlet UIView *portraitPlayView;
IBOutlet UIView *portraitGameHolderView;
IBOutlet UIView *loadingView;
IBOutlet UIView *welcomeView;
IBOutlet UIButton *continueButton;
IBOutlet UIView *aboutView;
IBOutlet UIView *playView;
IBOutlet UIView *rhythmView;
//IBOutlet UIView *levelSelectView;
IBOutlet UILabel *musicNotation;
IBOutlet CoinsController *coinsController;
IBOutlet RhythmController *rhythmController;


IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *remainingTurnsLabels;
IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *scoreLabels;
IBOutlet HighscoreController *highscoreController;

CoinsGame* previousGame;
BOOL isPlayingGame;
}
-(void)setPreviousGame:(CoinsGame*)aCoinsGame;
-(CoinsGame*)currentGame;

- (IBAction)continueGameClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)newGameClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)highScoresClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)aboutClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)aboutDoneClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)highscoreDoneClicked:(id)sender;

-(void)loadImages;
-(void)showPlayView: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
-(void)doPause; 

@end
```

In GameController.m , the method is

```
// RhythmDelegate Tasks
-(void)gameOver:(RhythmController*)aRhythmController{

NSLog(@"Came into gameOver delegated task"); 
[self.view addSubview: welcomeView];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your delegate variable is nil at your break point. if yes then you forgot to setting the delegate.

You can easily set it in you viewdidload method of gamecontroller after you have created your RhythmController this:

```
rythmcontroller.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to set the `GameController` instance as the `RhythmController`'s delegate.  Simply implementing the protocol for a delegate doesn't magically make the delegate connections.  You need a line like this somewhere:

```
myRhythmController.delegate = myGameController;
```

As a note: delegates are typically a `weak` reference, or are `assign` properties.  This is to prevent retain loops between the delegate object and the original object

Comment: Thanks .. I reckon this works, but in my case I don't have the reference to myGameController and myRhythmController in the same file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @PierLim the fact of the matter is that at some point you need to have both references in the same place in order to set the delegate.

Comment: Hi Dan, yes that's technically true - that place would be my GameController file, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forgot to set the delegate property for the rhythmController instance?

If you would have created the code you would have done somehting like this:

```
rhythmController = [[RhythmController alloc] init];
rhythemController.delegate = self;
...
[rhythmController release];
```

Where "self" is the GameController instance.